# AutoComplete TextBox without Webservices in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete

I am trying to set autocomplete on textbox. I have used this example:
http://sapnashukla.blogspot.com/2014/05/to-create-autocomplete-textbox-without.html

I can't get a result. When I trying to type text I am getting this result after TextBox:

```
Type test
<
!
D
O
C
T
Y
P
E
h
t
m
l
<
>
and etc..
```

What I should do for it?

Somebody can explain and help me?

I have tried this too:
aspx.cs

public partial class manage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
{
    return AutoFillProducts(prefixText);

}

private static List<string> AutoFillProducts(string prefixText)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BNConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
        {
            com.CommandText = "select person from table where " + "person like @Search + '%'";

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", prefixText);
            com.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            List<string> countryNames = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    countryNames.Add(sdr["person"].ToString());
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return countryNames;


        }

    }
}
```

}

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="manage.aspx.cs" Inherits="XX.Mobilus.manage" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" 
        CompletionInterval="1" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" UseContextKey="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

the blog had only one(1) parameter from its function[image]

, have you tried removing the ", int count"?

Comment: The blog have one(1) parameter. You have written for removing "int count" but there isin't parameter in funciton.
Talking about my second funciont not from blog. There are prefixText and int count paramet. 
Both cases have a same result...have you more idea?

Comment: the blog have one parameter, that's why your GetCompletionList function must also have one parameter, not 2

Comment: I have tried ant this example - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

I don't understand why I can't get a result. Where and why should I find a problem?

Comment: I have tried functions AutoFillProducts and GetCompletionList with one parameter but nothing...

Comment: I'm actually able to follow and execute the instructions within the blog. How was it?

Comment: I have did by http://sapnashukla.blogspot.com/2014/05/to-create-autocomplete-textbox-without.html 
I can't get a result, don't work autocomplete.. I think that it doesn't call to aspx.cs method...

Comment: The main reason of the problem is when i type text on textbox I am geting this result:
<
!
D
O
C
T
Y
P
E
h
t
m
l
<
>
and etc..